# How do I create an object with sub functions in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not very good at C++ so prepare for improper use of terms.

Basically I want to gather a bunch of functions inside a sub class of another class, so I would interface with it kinda like this:

```
mainWindow.add.menubar();
            ^- this is the part I don't know how to do
```

My class looks something like this at the moment:

```
namespace GUI {
    class Window {
    public:
        std::string title = "Empty Title";
        int show();
        // Using a struct didn't work but it's what I have at the moment.
        struct add {
            int menubar();
        };
    };
}
```

Obviously I could simply use `mainWindow.addMenubar()` but it would be much nicer to add it to a subclass (sub object? I don't know, I'm more used to Javascript programming).

And yes, I'm basically creating my own GUI framework with insufficient C++ expertise, I know it's a bad idea, but it didn't stop me from modifying the Linux kernel to allow me to install Nethunter on my Samsung S4 and it's not gonna stop me now.

Comment: You don't, yet, have a sub-object. You have a nested type (`add`), but you aren't creating any instances (objects) of it, and trying to invoke non-static method on a type.

Comment: To call `Window::add::menubar` you need to create an instance of `Window::add`. This instance could live inside `Window` if you'd like.

Comment: Looks like you could use [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Note that nested struct definition can be private, while the instance of it should be public.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject Window* pointer to the struct Add() constructor, something like:

```
namespace GUI {
    class Window {
    public:
        std::string title = "Empty Title";
        Add add;     // <- NOTICE: this is an instance of struct Add
                     // which holds the pointer to the window you want 
                     // to draw on
    public:
        Window() : add{this} {}
        int show();
        // Using a struct didn't work but it's what I have at the moment.
        struct Add {
            Window* win;
            Add(Window* w) : win{w} {}
            int menubar() {
                //  here you can use win to draw the puppy :)
            }
        };
    };
}
```

and then use it like

```
Widow w; 
w.add.menubar();
```

Of course, you could do more styling here (for the real world code): separate declaration from definition via *.h/*.cpp files, hide the data you dont want to expose with private, declare Add as a friend class etc.

Answer (score 2):

For it to work, `add` must be a variable:

```
#include <string>

namespace GUI {
    class Window {
    public:
        std::string title = "Empty Title";
        int show();
        // Using a struct didn't work but it's what I have at the moment.
        struct Add {
            int menubar();
        };
        Add add;
    };
}
```